Maven - Apache Avro Matlab installation problem
During installation MATLAB Interface for Apache Avro I alwaice recive the same ERROR: ""
c:\Users\user\matlab-avro\Software\Java>mvn dependency:copy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------< com.mathworks.avro.sdk:matlabavro >------------------
[INFO] Building MATLAB Interface for Avro 0.4
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- dependency:3.6.1:copy (default-cli) @ matlabavro ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.337 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-04-09T00:42:06+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.6.1:copy (default-cli) on project matlabavro: Either artifact or artifactItems is required  -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

The same errors recieved on 2 different computers (with windows 10 and 11). How I can fix it?
Used:
JAVA JDK-22
Apache Maven 3.9.6
Windows 10 and 11
https://github.com/mathworks-ref-arch/matlab-avro/tree/master
I need to resolve problem and build JAR file.
